# separate big table in html into small tables

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table but I have to separate it into separate tables. They must be separated by "table_title" and the content of the tables is "table_line" I would greatly appreciate your support

> ```
> <thead>  
>     <tr>
>       <th>Product</th>
>       <th></th>
>     </tr>
>   </thead>
>  <tbody>
>       <tr>
>          <td colspan="2" class="titulo_tabla">Title 1</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Resolución de la pantalla</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">1366 x 768 Pixeles</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Pantalla táctil</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">No</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Tipo HD</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">HD</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Retroiluminación LED</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Si</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Relación de aspecto nativa</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">16:9</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Pantalla antirreflejante</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Si</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Brillo de pantalla</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">220 cd / m²</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Densidad del pixel</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">112 ppi</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Espacio de color RGB</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">NTSC</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Gama de colores</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">45%</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Máxima velocidad de actualización</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">60 Hz</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Razón de contraste (típica)</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">400:1</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td colspan="2" class="titulo_tabla">TItle 2</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Modelo del procesador</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">i5-1135G7</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Frecuencia del procesador turbo</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">4.2 GHz</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Familia de procesador</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Intel® Core™ i5 de 11ma Generación</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Núcleos del procesador</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">4</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Caché del procesador</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">8 MB</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Tipo de cache en procesador</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Smart Cache</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Frecuencia configurable TDP-up</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">2.4 GHz</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">TDP-up configurable</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">28 W</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">TDP-down configurable</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">12 W</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Frecuencia configurable TDP-down</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">0.9 GHz</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td colspan="2" class="titulo_tabla">Title 3</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Cantidad de puertos tipo A USB 3.2 Gen 1 (3.1 Gen 1)</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">2</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Puertos Ethernet LAN (RJ-45)</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">1</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Número de puertos HDMI</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">1</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Versión HDMI</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">1.4</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Combo de salida de auriculares / micrófono del puerto</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Si</td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Tipo de puerto de carga</td>
>          <td class="linea_tabla">Toma de entrada de CC</td>
>       </tr>
>    </tbody>
> </table>
>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
> <script>
> let types = [... new Set($('table.original tr .titulo_tabla').get().map(type => type.textContent))];
>
> //create a container for the cloned tables
> $('table.original').after(`<h4>After:</h4><div class="cloned-tables"></div>`)
>
> //loop over types, clone tables, modify accordingly
> $.each(types, function(index, type) {
>   $(`<p class="type">${type}</p>${$('table.original')[0].outerHTML}`)
>     .appendTo('.cloned-tables')
>     .find('.titulo_tabla').each(function() {
>       //if (this.textContent !== type) { this.parentElement.remove();  }        
>       //this.remove();
>   });
> });
> </script>
> ```

I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.
I would like to separate by table title, any help is welcome.

[descripcion de código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lPbm.png)

Answer (score -1):

Can you just make two separate tables similar to this:

```
<tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" class="titulo_tabla">Title 1</td>
      </tr>
...
<tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" class="titulo_tabla">Title 2</td>
      </tr>
```